# Magento after place order it going to default theme

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have an issue while clicking the place order in my magento website it just going to standard theme I have installed a separate theme named proclean red normally it will go to that theme but now its going to the default standard theme. May I know what is the issue so I can solve this issue.

I have attached the screenshot of that default page theme which right now redirecting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because checkout/success.phtml is not present or misconfigured in your custom theme.

In order to use checkout/success.phtml from your custom theme, you need to ensure two things.

```
In the Admin side, you need to set current theme as your custom theme. For the sake of illustration, I am calling theme name as custom_theme

Then you need to put your phtml template at app\design\frontend\default\custom_theme/template/checkout/sucess.phtml.
```

Note :- Here I assume, package is default. You can check the package name in the theme and backend.

So make sure that file does exist in your custom theme. Clear all cache and then try again.

Comment: Hi I have changed it like that you have mentioned but no changes its still redirecting to default success.phtml after deleting the file also it is going to struture for the default theme layout. My question only this succes page is going to the default theme after placing order remaining pages still remain the new custom theme only dont know any idea from your side